# How to change a property value of another layer in After Effects?

Tags: expression, after-effects

I have 2 layers in the same comp:

1. Video Layer
2. Control Layer (null Object)

Basically i need to write an expression on the Control Layer which sets a specific value on a property on the Video Layer.
In other words, i need to change a property in "Video Layer" from an expression on "Control Layer".

For example, for a better comprehension, if i write the following expression under the Control Layer scale property

```
thisComp.layer("VideoLayer.mp4").transform.scale
```

It takes the scale of Video Layer and applies it to the Control Layer WHICH IS NOT WHAT I WANT. What i need to do is almost the opposite: i need the expression to set the VideoLayer.mp4 scale to a specific value. Is there a way to do that in AE?

Answer (score 0):

First add a expression control slider to your control layer via "Effects> Expression controls> Slider".
Then add the following expression to the scale property of the Video Layer

```
sliderValue = thisComp.layer("Control Layer").effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
[sliderValue, sliderValue]
```